# Why does my direct Equals call pass, but fails when nested?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, struct, nunit

I am attempting to implement `Equals` overrides for some structs in my code. I have the following "child" struct

```cs
public struct ChildStruct
{
    public bool Valid;
    public int Value1;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) 
         {
             return false;
         }

         ChildStruct other = (ChildStruct) obj;

         return Valid == other.Valid && Surface == other.Value1;
    }
}
```

And this "parent" struct where one member is an array of `ChildStructs`

```cs
public struct ParentStruct
{
    public int Id;
    public ChildStruct[] children;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) 
         {
             return false;
         }

         ParentStruct other = (ParentStruct) obj;

         // am I comparing ChildStructs array correctly?
         return Id == other.Id && children == other.children;
    }
}
```

In my Nunit testing of overriding the `Equals` methods, directly comparing objects of type ChildStruct pass, but my unit test of the ParentStructs are failing. Am I missing something in the `Equals` override in the ParentStruct to account for the array? Is the child `Equals` method not enumerated to all elements in the children array?

Nunit code:

```cs
[Test]
public void ChildEqual()
{ 
    var child1 = new ChildStruct{Valid = true, Value1 = 1};
    var child2 = new ChildStruct{Valid = true, Value1 = 1};

    // passes!
    Assert.AreEqual(child1, child2);
}

[Test]
public void ParentEqual()
{ 
    var child1 = new ChildStruct{Valid = true, Value1 = 1};
    var child2 = new ChildStruct{Valid = true, Value1 = 1};

    var parent1 = new ParentStruct{Id = 1, children = new[] {child1, child2}}
    var parent2 = new ParentStruct{Id = 1, children = new[] {child1, child2}}

    // fails during checking for equality of children array!
    Assert.AreEqual(parent1, parent2);
}
```

Comment: Comparing two arrays does not compare each item in those arrays with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine what makes two arrays of `ChildStruct`s equal, for the purpose of `ParentStruct` equality, and change the last line of `ParentStruct`'s equals method accordingly. For example, if they're only supposed to be "equal" if they contain equivalent children *in the same order*, this would work:

```
return Id == other.Id && children.SequenceEqual(other.children);
```

Comment: Ahhh got it. I was making the false assumption that calling `Equals` on an array would delegate behind the scenes to each items own `Equals` method.